# Page specific HTML blocks in PlayFramework 1.x

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

In the classic groovy based Play 1.x templating engine, is there a way to define a block of text that can be referenced by the parent template?  I know you can use #{set name:value}, but that just set a single string and I really need the ability to create an entire text block.   What I'm looking for is something like this in my page:

```
#{set name:"page_actions" \}
<div class='button-group'>
   <a href='#'>Add Item</a>
   <a href='#'>Show all</a>
</div>
#{/set}
```

Then in my parent template do something like

```
<header>
   #{get page_actions /}
</header>
...
<footer>
   #{get page_actions /}
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom template tag to do that : http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/templates#tags

Just put your html in a app/views/tags/myfile.html and call the tag #{myfile /} in your main html file.

You can use variables inside the template tag but you reference them with a _ at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  #{set "variable_name"/} works perfectly.  You need need to leave off the map (i.e. don't use name:value -- just use "name".